# Will there be mining pools with the Proof-of-Stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake, mining-pools

Ethereum will eventually move to Proof-of-Stake algorithm. I guess it is a very basic question, but how the mining pools are supposed to work in that case (if at all)?

Answer (score 4):

There may well be multisig stake pools which allow multiple parties to stake their Eth but there will not be mining pools in the sense of contributing processing power to a pool.

Answer (score 3):

Though mining pools will not be available, they will be replaced with stake pools where a multisig public [stake pool smart contract](https://medium.com/rocket-pool/rocket-pool-your-new-casper-friendly-ethereum-pos-pool-in-alpha-75709bd19936) will be used as in case of [Rocket Pool](https://www.rocketpool.net/) where one needs to claim a stake by depositing some amount of Ether and if that block is validated. Note: Proof of stake does nothing with mining instead it is based on validation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that for participating in PoS, you'll have to run a full node. There won't be any pools and we will throw our 280x's away.

Comment: Don't throw them away please :-)